# MySQL - insert without updating certain indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

We have a table with multiple indexes. Some indexes are only used when we are analyzing data in the table once a week, otherwise they are not used at all.

Since we are adding/updating close to a thousand rows every second, we'd like to optimize write speed. We really don't care if some of those indexes are not updated since we are not going to use them in regular queries. So our ideal scenario would be

1. Write to table without updating some indexes (but update other indexes)
2. Manually update those indexes when we are analyzing data once a week.

One option is to create a temporary table when analyzing but our table has over hundred million rows and no practical.

Any insight how we can achieve above or better alternatives?

Comment: How are you doing `INSERT`, exactly? I get the feeling you're doing single-row inserts over-and-over instead of single multi-row inserts...

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not have a way to avoid selected index updates.

You have mentioned using an extra table, but copying 100M rows over *plus* adding *all* indexes to the new table is quite costly.

Establishing replication would take some work.  The Replica could have extra indexes that the Primary does not have.

What kind of processing is done with the table when it needs the extra indexes?  That sounds like something that a "Summary Table" could make *more* efficient with *fewer* indexes.  Each night, you would augment the Summary table with the day's items.  The Summary table would be much smaller and have subtotals for the day.  And it would have whatever indexes are useful.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: I agree, that's the reason we are not copying data. Currently we are maintaining multiple indexes and using them but the the idea is to avoid them. I will check summary table link, thank you for it.

Comment: Having extra indexes is a _minor_ burden on `INSERTs`.  Perhaps, it is not too much burden?  Or maybe we can improve the performance of the Inserts some other way?  Would you care to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?